# Como guardo el valor de un elemento de un struct en otro struct en C

Tags: c

Quiero guardar el valor de un `struct` en este caso el valor es el nombre de un cliente y lo quiero guardar en otro `struct`.

Esta es la función donde quiero guardar un elemento en otro struct, quiero guardar el nombre del cliente de la `struct` "clientes" en la `struct` "citas "

```
void Funcitas(){
    system("cls");
printf("1.Crear Cita\t2.Mostrar Cita\n");
int op;
printf("Ingresa una opcion: \n");
scanf("%d",&op);
switch(op){
    case 1:

        clientes[i].nombre=&citas[i].cliente;
        tecnicos[i].nombre=&citas[i].tecnico;
        i++;
        Zita();
        system("pause");
        Funcitas();

    break;
```

Comment: Dado que no has publicado el código de la definición del struct, difícilmente vamos a poder ayudarte.

Comment: El código no compila. ¿Puedes poner otro ejemplo de tu problema?

Answer (score 0):

necesitamos que publiques la declaración de los struct(o en lo posible el codigo entero para indicarte los errores).

¿Declaraste los struct dentro del main? 
De ser así, le deberías pasar a la función, cada struct por referencia para que almacene los cambios.

Además de eso, ¿en que parte del código hiciste la definición de la variable i?

Saludos